# Sniffer for flash application

Tags: flash, sniffer

I am searching an addin for firefox or any other software to sniff trafic between flash application and server side. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/)? And, obviously, there is always Wireshark.

Comment: Wireshark works! I ran [this flash](http://ai.bluemars.com/chat/), set filter in wireshark `ip.addr == 173.255.244.75` (found by exclusion, unfiltered gave a huge amount of extraneous packets). All chatbot interaction packets shown.

Answer (score 2):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) will show you network traffic between the browser (including Flash) and the server.  Additionally, there's [Flashbug](http://blog.coursevector.com/flashbug), which hooks up traces to Firebug.

Comment: hmmm. flash tab of network console doesnt catch flash traffic for my case. I really donnt know why.

Comment: @Neir0, you've said that my answer (now deleted), Live HTTP Headers, didn't work. And now Firebug doesn't work. Did you write the flash app, and you're sure it's connecting?